# docker run failing in Fedora 22

Tags: fedora, docker

I am using the latest version of Fedora 22 with all updates.

I am trying out docker and getting permission denied failures.  I am not seeing the below issue when running as root. Do i really need root access to use docker ?

```
$ ps -ef | grep docker
root       931     1  0 10:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/docker -d --selinux-enabled
codingf+  2953  2809  0 10:37 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto docker
```

I am running docker daemon

```
$ docker version
Client version: 1.7.1.fc22
Client API version: 1.19
Package Version (client): docker-1.7.1-8.gitb6416b7.fc22.x86_64
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): b6416b7/1.7.1
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.19/version: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?


$ docker info
Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.19/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?

$ docker run hello-world
Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.19/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

Comment: You can also put your user in the docker group, but that effectively gives you root anyway. [The full explanation is here.](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/08/why-we-dont-let-non-root-users-run-docker-in-centos-fedora-or-rhel/)

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Thanks for the article. Its seems we need SUDO or ROOT accesss for running dockerized apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try **sudo** docker run. Docker service runs as root, and the unix domain socket requires root permission to talk to.

Comment: The OP explicitly said, "I am not seeing below issue when running as a ROOT".

Comment: @santosh - So we need to sudo or ROOT access inorder to run the dockerized apps ?

Comment: Yes, docker containers can only be started as root [out of box]. It's less damaging as the child permission only contained with in the container. You can spawn a docker process as a different user however by passing -u <uid> option.